# How do I make my compiled program not immediately close when it finishes running the code?

Tags: rust

I'm trying to test out if the compiled rust program is portable but the window immediately closes. Opening the program in a terminal in vs code doesn't immediately close the program but waits for you to enter any key before closing. Is there a function or any code that would make it act like that?

Comment: This documentation could help you https://rust-cli.github.io/book/in-depth/signals.html. If you run your programs in command line on powershell, or cmd, is not close.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Opening the program in a terminal in vs code doesn't immediately close the program but waits for you to enter any key before closing.

I'd guess that's just the vscode behaviour. Immediately closing the window is the normal behaviour for a program terminating.

> Is there a function or any code that would make it act like that?

Reading from stdin usually does the trick.

Comment: I guess my first hunch on what I should do was already right. Thanks anyways.